# Accessing hosted feature layers in ArcGIS Portal

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

The feature layers can be accessed using the item type, is there any way to retrieve only the **hosted feature layers** from the Portal ??

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS(url='https://pythonapi.playground.esri.com/portal', username='arcgis_python', password='amazing_arcgis_123')
type(gis.content)
search_result = gis.content.search(query="", item_type="Feature Layer")
search_result
```

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000016853

Comment: Is this ArcGIS enterprise? And you want to also ignore any traditional feature services? (E.g from a Geodatabase as opposed to ArcGIS Data Store)